# Spring - Non Opinionated Conventions

Tags: spring

There are two things about the Spring documentation that seem to contradict each other.  I know I am probably over thinking this, but I want to see what others have to say about it :

> 1. Spring embraces flexibility and is not opinionated about how things should be done (ie if a framework is opinionated, it locks or guides you into their way of doing things). [Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/overview.html#overview-philosophy)
> 2. Spring also embraces convention over configuration. [Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/overview.html#overview-getting-started)

Doesn't the existence of a convention indicate that Spring has a way of doing things?

How can Spring say that it is not opinionated when it also says that there is a convention?

Like I said, I am probably over thinking this...

Comment: The fact that it uses conventions doesn't mean you must use those conventions.

Comment: How do you understand the term "Convention"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you mixed a little the two sentences.
It doesn't tell that the Spring conventions are not opinionated.
A convention is always opinionated.

The first point is :

> Accommodate diverse perspectives. Spring embraces flexibility and is
>   not opinionated about how things should be done. It supports a wide
>   range of application needs with different perspectives.

And the second one is :

> It is based on the Spring Framework, favors convention over
>   configuration, and is designed to get you up and running as quickly as
>   possible.

In fact these two points are respected by Spring but these are not applied to the same level.
The first point refers to the flexibility that Spring provides as options to design your application.
The second point refers to the convention over configuration way provided by Spring to reduce the boiler plate code. And this is right whatever the options that you want to use.

---

Here are some details with examples :

The first point means that Spring provides multiple ways to do a thing. It doesn't force you to use a specific way to achieve your goal. 
I will give you some examples to illustrate that.
For example suppose you want to do some persistence operations. Spring provides support to achieve it with a wide variety of ways : JDBC, JPA, NoSQL...
And as you dig further, it is the same things for lower level things.
As data persistence helper Spring provides a variety of things : `JdbcTemplate`,  `CrudRepository`, `JpaRepository and` so for...
Another example : as you perform the dependency injection, you don't have a single way to do that : you can use setter, field, constructor or even factory method injection.
This kind of thing is the *Spring flexibility*.

About the second point : conventions over configuration is a very basic of Spring.
It relies on the fact that as you want to use a specific component, feature, any thing provided by Spring, it will be set by default with a common default configuration that is also the common way which the most of users need.
For example, beans are more frequently singleton than prototype.  So Spring configure by default the prototype scope for beans.  Other example : naming explicitly each beans is a hell. So Spring uses the camelcase of the simple class name to define the bean name.
A last example that shows that the two points are not contradictory : you have multiple ways to specify the dependency injection of a bean.
If you define a constructor with parameter, the injection option (*flexibility*) will be automatically applied (*convention over configuration*). You don't need to specify `@Autowired` because Spring makes it a convention.
You have hundreds of example like that in Spring and Spring Boot that will further in the convention over configuration way.

Comment: Great answer! I appreciate the fact that you provided examples too.

Comment: The second quote comes from Spring Boot not from Spring. Spring Boot isn't the same as Spring. Those things seem to mingle here in the answer. The question was regarding Spring itself not the other portofolio projects.

Comment: @M. Deinum In my answer I didn't refer to Spring Boot specificities but at the end. I would think  that I adding a little part on that could be interesting as Spring Boot is opinionated, contrary to Spring. What is your mind ?

Comment: What about the examples given?  Are the examples given an incorrect representation for Spring overall?  I thought the examples were great since they did not seem to reference an particular project

Comment: I was referring to the the second quote (that is from Spring Boot reference guide). Spring also has some conventions which you can quite easily override or ignore but they are still there.

Comment: Only `@Autowired` and `JdbcTemplate` are from Spring itself. The other are from other portfolio projects (Spring Data Common and Spring Data JPA).

Comment: @M. Deinum  In fact the second quote refers to Spring Boot but I referenced it with my edit. You can notice that the OP quote and the documentation don't match exactly. I will update it to stay on Spring only.

Comment: @goob  I don't think that the examples give an incorrect representation of the Spring behavior.  M. Deinum underlined that Spring Boot is not Spring and that I also illustrate with portfolios/extensions of Spring.

Comment: @M. Deinum In fact the recent enough Spring documentations mingles Spring and Spring Boot : https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.18.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/ or https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#spring-core So i will leave like that.

Comment: How is a different layout but still the same content mingling 2 projects? In fact the OP even linked to the correct sections of the Spring reference guide.

Comment: @M. Deinum  The OP didn't link anything. As said, I linked it.  "How is a different layout but still the same content mingling 2 projects?" Check the links : https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/overview.html#overview and  https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.18.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#overview-getting-started-with-spring.  Both mingle the two projects . But conventions over configuration are not born with Spring Boot. So I suppose that Spring decided to mingle them in the Spring official documentation to promote Spring Boot.

Answer (score 1):

> Doesn't the existence of a convention indicate that Spring has a way of doing things?

A "way of doing things out of the box that is intended to make it easy to get started".

> How can Spring say that it is not opinionated when it also says that there is a convention?

**Convention:** a way in which something is usually done, especially within a particular area or activity

Spring certainly has conventions (`#2`), but strives to offer every opportunity to provide an alternative solution (`#1`) to replace the default convention.

If I were to rewrite a verbose `#1` and `#2` together:

> Spring embraces flexibility with opinions on conventional defaults that should make implementation easier for most engineers (i.e. "convention over configuration"). However, Spring is not opinionated about how things should ultimately be implemented if you choose to override the conventional defaults.

Comment: Hopefully you do work for the Spring team.  That way you could improve it.  The way you worded it is much more concise.